# How to deploy an app from xcode with personal team

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have issues with signing, which you can see below. It says that there are no profiles and I failed to register the bundle identifier. I am just testing xcode and want to try my app on my iPhone, so I use the free version. Is there a way to remove these warnings?

[image]